# Why does Spring Data REST ignore cascade ops on an associated entity?

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa, spring-data-rest

**Background**

I have an `Car` entity with a `@ManyToOne` relationship with a `Make` entity:

```
@Entity
public class Car {
 
  @Id
  Long id;

  @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
  Make make;
}

@Entity
public class Make {

  @Id
  Long id;
  String name;
}
```

Both `Car` and `Make` have repositories:

```
public interface CarRepository extends CrudRepository<Car, Long> {
}

public interface MakeRepository extends CrudRepository<Make, Long> {
}
```

**Problem**

When a client issues an HTTP POST request to the Spring Data REST endpoint `/api/cars` with a payload of:

```
{
  "id":null, 
  "make": {
    "id": null,
    "name": "Toyota"
  }
}
```

A new car is created and persisted in the database but its `Make` is set as null in the DB.

**What I expected**

Since `CascadeType.ALL` is specified and the `make` of the car has a null `id`, I thought a new `Make` record would be persisted in the DB and that the new `Car` record would have its foreign key to `Make` (i.e., `makeId`) set to that new `Make` record.

**Observations**

- If `Make` does not have its own repository (i.e., I delete the `MakeRepository`), the make will be persisted as expected and associated with the new car.
- If I annotate the `make` field in `Car` with `@RestResource(exported = false)`, the make will be persisted as expected and associated with the new car.
- If I save `Make` first and then set that on the `Car`, the make will obviously be persisted and then associated with the new car.

**Questions**

Is there a way to save the make of a car without adding `@RestResource` to the `make` field or without a separate save? Where can I find Spring documentation describing this behavior?

Answer (score 0):

**Why Make (i.e., makeId)  is set as null in the DB :**

> - There is no `GeneratedValue` in your `Car` and `Make` entity

**How we can fix / solve :**

- Update your entity like below

  @Entity
  public class Car {

  ```
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  Long id;

  @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
  Make make;
  ```

  }

  @Entity
  public class Make {

  ```
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  Long id;

  String name;
  ```

  }
- To save a new Car and a new Make with a single save ie `carRepository.save(car)` your payload will be like below

```
    {
      "id":null, 
      "make": {
        "id": null,
        "name": "Toyota"
      }
    }
```

- To Update an old Car and an old Make with a single save ie `carRepository.save(car)` your payload will be like below

```
    {
      "id":2, 
      "make": {
        "id": 21,
        "name": "Toyota"
      }
    }
```